# Store lists/checklist into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to make a demo application that is able to ask a user if he/she has followed the correct methods to build an item.

I have created a 'checklist' for the user to fill in as he/she builds the item. For example some of the questions could be:

1. Have you received the correct parts?
2. Are the parts in good condition?
3. Are you building a chair?
4. Do you have the correct specifications for the chair?
5. ...
6. ...

...

And so on...

So these questions have yes/no answers only. My plan was to create a table and call each column by the questions' number. So column 1 will be called '1' and it's the first question. Column 2 will be called '2' and it's the second question and so on.

So this table will be called Chair inspection. I then have another table called Table inspection with its own set of checklist questions.

This data is captured using an android application. The development of the application is done. Just need advice on the database part.

Is this the correct approach to storing the user's inputs?

[image]

Comment: No. A database table is not a spreadsheet. Please see about 'normalisation'

Comment: @Strawberry so normalization is about "organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a database to ensure that their dependencies are properly enforced by database integrity constraints". My table users ID as the primary key and I added a user column so I know who the answers belong to. Would you suggest I use a single column for the yes/no answers instead of multiple coloumns as I did?

Comment: What happens when you want to add a seventh item to the checklist?

Comment: @Strawberry if more questions are to be added I wanted to just add an additional column , "ALTER TABLE `dummy`.`chair` 
ADD COLUMN `7` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `6`;"

Comment: That's a really poor solution. Additions to the database should not require structural change, and queries against this dataset will likely be woefully inefficient. Obviously, you can do what you like, but if you're going to use an RDBMS then it seems silly not to structure your schema accordingly. For a higher level discussion on the whys and wherefors of normalisation, you might do better in the DBA forum; at any rate, a more in depth answer is above my pay-grade.

Comment: @Strawberry so I guess in databases if the solution works then it is 'correct'. However, it is not correct in terms of being efficient with the memory used in the database (like the user below answer). Unlike for example electrical work, just because the light comes on does not mean what you did was right (in this case the switch was not wired to code). Will keep on studying this field so I can find better ways of using databases.

Comment: One advantage of a database over a spreadsheet is that it allows easy analysis of data, independent of the structure (see atomisation). Spreadsheets have their place too, but if you want a spreadsheet, use Excel.

Comment: @Strawberry Excel is not an option because the application dumps the data to my desktop server over Wifi. (Desktop and phone application are connected via Wifi on the same network)

Comment: I don't know why that would preclude the use of Excel, but anyway... we digress

Comment: @Strawberry so you telling me I can use Excel as a database like MYSQL???? So what will the connection string in my android app look like because for MySQL is it "DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.178.25.1:4306/chair", "Name", "password")". This is interesting!...

Answer (score 1):

I advice you have three tables, one for the questions, the other for the users who will be answering those questions and the last one is for the answers, then you establish the relationship between those three tables. That means Many users can answer many questions. Therefore there will be many to many relationship between users and questions. Then there will be relationship between questions and answers and answer with the users who responded to the questions.

I think that way you will be able to avoid redundancy and simplify the process of updating, and retrieving you data.

Answer (score 0):

A normalised schema might be as follows (incomplete, and ignoring 'tables' for the time being) :

```
inspection
inspection_id* item inspected_by date

inspection_detail
inspection_id* checklist_id* status 

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```